# add SPListItem to a SPListItemCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have the following code for load a list from sharepoint site.

ALl is working well exept a SPList item to SPListItemCollection.

```
 private void Data_load()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            string currentName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Editor'/><Value Type='Person or Group'>" + currentName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spdev-6/"))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList lists = web.GetList("Lists/Advertisements");

                    SPListItemCollection items = lists.GetItems(query);

                    if (items.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow dr=null;
                        SPListItemCollection ITEM = null;
                        foreach(SPListItem item in items)
                        {
                            string A = item["Approval Status"].ToString();
                            if(A== "2")
                            {
                                ITEM.Add(item);

                            }


                        }
                        if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
                            lbldata.Text = "No data to show";

                      //  dt = items.GetDataTable();


                    }
                    else
                        lbldata.Text = "No data to show";



                    GridViewD.DataSource = dt;
                    GridViewD.DataBind();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Advertisement"] = dt;


                }
            }

        }
```

Now in if(A== "2"){ ITEM.Add(item);  }

I want to add  SPListItem to a  SPListItemCollection. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add an item into `null` because your `ITEM` is null. I don't know what error you are getting ( your don't write it) but you must initialize your collection:

```
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
          DataRow dr=null;
          SPListItemCollection ITEM = ... //
          foreach(SPListItem item in items)
          {
              string A = item["Approval Status"].ToString();
              if(A== "2")
              {
                 SPListItem myItem = ITEM.Add();
                 // set your item's fields here 
                 // Use indexers on this object for each field to assign specific values, and then call the Update method on the item to effect changes in the database.
                 myItem["Approval Status"] = item["Approval Status"];
                 ...
                 myItem.Update();
              }
          }
          if(dt.Rows.Count==0)
             lbldata.Text = "No data to show";

             //  dt = items.GetDataTable();

    }
```

Comment: ERROR: has some invalid argument.

Comment: At SPListItemCollection ITEM = new SPListItemCollection(); the type Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPListItemCollection() has no constructor defined

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh I don't see your code and Sharepoint, so you need to initialize it and then use the code above

Comment: for  SPListItemCollection ITEM = null its invalid argument at  ITEM.Add(item); and At SPListItemCollection ITEM = new SPListItemCollection(); the type Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPListItemCollection() has no constructor defined  facing these problems at the moment

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh I Unserstand.I cant initialize the collection because I don't see your Sharepoint and all your codes,you must it do alone and the use the above code I show you

Comment: I want selected items from Items to ITEM plea se tell me how will i get them